# How to reload apex:include pages

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a apex tab panel which has 2 tabs

```
<apex:tabPanel switchType="server" selectedTab="tabdetails" id="CaseTabPanel" tabClass="activeTab" inactiveTabClass="inactiveTab">
    <apex:tab label="Unclaimed Ticket" name="OpenActivities"  id="tabOpenAct" >
        <apex:actionsupport event="ontabenter" action="{!viewdata}" rerender="ref"/>
        <apex:outputpanel id="ref">
            <apex:include pageName="UnclaimedTicketPage" />
        </apex:outputpanel>
    </apex:tab>
    <apex:tab id="claim_id"  label="Claimed Ticket" name="OpenActivitiesg"  onComplete="window.location.reload(true);"> 
        <apex:include pageName="ClaimedTicketPage"  />
    </apex:tab>
</apex:tabPanel>
```

I have to do few operations on each tab. I select a few records in 1st tab and click to move.... When I visit tab2 it's showing old records... But when I refresh the page it is showing moved records from tab1. When I move records from tab 2 to tab 1 i.e vice versa, the same thing is happening.

Is there any way to reload two tabs when an event occurs on one tab?

Comment: now i have changed switchType="server" to switchType="client" in apex:tabPanel and added this atrribute in apex:tab now changes in second tab getting reflected in 1st one but changes in 1st tab not getting reflected in second one...

Answer (score 2):

You could add another `rerender` target (the include on the second tab) in your first tab:

```
<apex:actionsupport event="ontabenter" action="{!viewdata}" rerender="ref,claimedTicketPage"/>
```

Of course, you'll need to add the id to your `<apex:include>`

```
<apex:include id="claimedTicketPage" pageName="ClaimedTicketPage" />
```

You might find that `switchType="ajax"` works best with these settings